# What is the fastest way to calculate total rows in a a huge SQL Server table with conditions

Tags: sql-server

After some surfing on the internet, I have found a way to calculate the total rows in a SQL Server table which is pretty fast.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(p.rows) 
FROM 
    sys.partitions AS p
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables AS t ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas AS s ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
WHERE
    t.name = N'table_name'
    AND s.name = N'dbo'
    AND p.index_id IN (0,1)
```

However, this code returns the exact total number rows of the table.

But, in my case, I am implementing soft deletes. So, I want to ignore those deleted rows which can be filtered with `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`.

That means, deleted rows will have deleted timestamps in `deleted_at` column.

Is there a way to calculate total rows of data faster than this with some conditions?

Comment: You're querying metadata, which does not contain the content of of your column obviously. What is wrong with `select count(*) from dbo.table_name where deleted_at is null` ?

Comment: It will take around 13 sec. As currently it have around `56679922` number of rows

Comment: then you need to create some kind of index. You can't get it directly from the sys tables. Might be helpful to post the SQL Server version you are running, and what you are doing with the data. Is this an ODS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take into account some actual data stored in your table, you obviously cannot use the "metadata" approach you've shown.

The probably fastest way to do a count would then be if you have a separate **filtered index** on a small (e.g. `INT`) and **non-nullable** column which excludes the condition you want to check for.

So you can try by adding this filtered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourTableName_Active
    ON dbo.YourTableName(deleted_at)
    WHERE deleted_at IS NOT NULL
```

**Update:** as @BenThul correctly notices - if you have a filtered index as suggested above, of course you can also check the metadata views for this index and its number of rows - try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(p.rows) 
FROM 
    sys.partitions AS p
INNER JOIN
    sys.indexes i ON i.[object_id] = p.[object_id] AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables AS t ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas AS s ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
WHERE
    t.name = N'table_name'
    AND s.name = N'dbo'
    AND i.Name = N'IX_YourTableName_Active'
```

Comment: I came here to say this, but with the addition of once that filtered indeed exists, there will be data for it in sys.partitions so you can do a metadata query on it then.

Comment: @BenThul: you're absolutely right - thanks! I've updated my response to include this information

Comment: @marc_s I got the idea. However, the exact solution for my case while creating index its `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` So, I removed that `NOT` and Thanks for @BenThul too. After this metadata query, my TotalRowsCount execution time is still `00:00:00`.

Comment: @saroj - that is my edit and therefore my mistake. However, now I have a question: what is your use case? In a typical scenario, soft-deleted data is a small percentage of the overall data and therefore "selective". Creating a filtered index where the filter isn't very selective is atypical.